# Flexbox button with SVG icon. The text overflowing the button

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the following code that behaves quite weird. My expectation is the button width change to let the contents appear inside the button.

Unfortunately the text is overflowing the button and I cannot find how to fix it.

Does anyone see what I do wrong with it? I've tried several different options and none of them worked.

```css
:root {
    --green: hsl(150.22deg 60.35% 44.51%);
    --green-dark: hsl(150.22deg 60.35% 35%);
    --green-light: hsl(148.89deg 87.1% 93.92%);
    --blue: hsl(202.86deg 77.78% 15.88%);
}

.btn {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-radius: 9999px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
}

.btn--green {
    background-color: var(--green);
    --tw-text-opacity: 1;
    color: rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
    transition-property: color, background-color, border-color, text-decoration-color, fill, stroke;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
    transition-duration: 300ms;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

.btn:has(svg) {
    gap: 0.75rem;
}

.btn svg {
    display: block;
    max-height: 16px;
    max-width: 16px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    fill: #fff;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn btn--green">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
        <path d="M37 33a3 3 0 0 0 2.2-1L61 10.2V91a3 3 0 0 0 6 0V10.2L88.8 32a3 3 0 0 0 4.2-4.2L66.1.8a3 3 0 0 0-.4-.3l-.3-.1a3 3 0 0 0-.3-.2 3 3 0 0 0-.3 0l-.2-.1a3 3 0 0 0-1.2 0h-.2a3 3 0 0 0-.3.1 3 3 0 0 0-.3.2l-.3.1a3 3 0 0 0-.4.4L35 27.8a3 3 0 0 0 2.1 5.1Z"></path>
        <path d="M125 88a3 3 0 0 0-3 3v22a9 9 0 0 1-9 9H15a9 9 0 0 1-9-9V91a3 3 0 0 0-6 0v22a15 15 0 0 0 15 15h98a15 15 0 0 0 15-15V91a3 3 0 0 0-3-3Z"></path>
    </svg>
    Button With Icon
</a>

<br>

<a href="#" class="btn btn--green">
    Button Without Icon
</a>
```

Comment: I think inline flex has issues with replaced elements, you may want to either use a font icon or add padding and absolutely position the image in the padding

Comment: The code you provided doesn't appear to do what you say it should. You say the text overflows when you have the icon in there, but I'm not seeing that. Can you clarify the issue, or make sure the code demonstrates the issue? I could just be missing it, but I don't see the issue.

Comment: @andrilla when the code is running you see the button with the icon has the same space left and right ? Also, yes, in the example code I entered the text does not overflowing probably because I didn't loaded the full CSS I have on my end that probably make some difference and on my local it overflowing. If your problem is to understand the issue, then let me clarify: "I need the button has same padding left and right when I have an svg icon in my flexbox button" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button doesn't have explicit width and the SVG neither. The SVG needs to have some intrinsic width. If you compare button widths from button 1 and button 2 in output from following demo. Then you'll see the buggy button is `16px` short.

```css
:root {
  --green: hsl(150.22deg 60.35% 44.51%);
  --green-dark: hsl(150.22deg 60.35% 35%);
  --green-light: hsl(148.89deg 87.1% 93.92%);
  --blue: hsl(202.86deg 77.78% 15.88%);
}

.btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-radius: 9999px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}

.btn--green {
  background-color: var(--green);
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
  transition-property: color, background-color, border-color, text-decoration-color, fill, stroke;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transition-duration: 300ms;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

.btn:has(svg) {
  gap: 0.75rem;
}

.btn svg {
  display: block;
  max-height: 16px;
  max-width: 16px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  fill: #fff;
}

.two svg {
  /* use relative unit 1rem */
  width: 1rem;
}
```

```html
1. Original code
<br>
<a href="#" class="btn btn--green">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
        <path d="M37 33a3 3 0 0 0 2.2-1L61 10.2V91a3 3 0 0 0 6 0V10.2L88.8 32a3 3 0 0 0 4.2-4.2L66.1.8a3 3 0 0 0-.4-.3l-.3-.1a3 3 0 0 0-.3-.2 3 3 0 0 0-.3 0l-.2-.1a3 3 0 0 0-1.2 0h-.2a3 3 0 0 0-.3.1 3 3 0 0 0-.3.2l-.3.1a3 3 0 0 0-.4.4L35 27.8a3 3 0 0 0 2.1 5.1Z"></path>
        <path d="M125 88a3 3 0 0 0-3 3v22a9 9 0 0 1-9 9H15a9 9 0 0 1-9-9V91a3 3 0 0 0-6 0v22a15 15 0 0 0 15 15h98a15 15 0 0 0 15-15V91a3 3 0 0 0-3-3Z"></path>
    </svg> Button With Icon
</a>

<br> 2. With 1rem width set on svg in CSS (<code>.two svg</code>)
<br>
<a href="#" class="btn btn--green two">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
        <path d="M37 33a3 3 0 0 0 2.2-1L61 10.2V91a3 3 0 0 0 6 0V10.2L88.8 32a3 3 0 0 0 4.2-4.2L66.1.8a3 3 0 0 0-.4-.3l-.3-.1a3 3 0 0 0-.3-.2 3 3 0 0 0-.3 0l-.2-.1a3 3 0 0 0-1.2 0h-.2a3 3 0 0 0-.3.1 3 3 0 0 0-.3.2l-.3.1a3 3 0 0 0-.4.4L35 27.8a3 3 0 0 0 2.1 5.1Z"></path>
        <path d="M125 88a3 3 0 0 0-3 3v22a9 9 0 0 1-9 9H15a9 9 0 0 1-9-9V91a3 3 0 0 0-6 0v22a15 15 0 0 0 15 15h98a15 15 0 0 0 15-15V91a3 3 0 0 0-3-3Z"></path>
    </svg> Button With Icon
</a>

<br> 3. With 16px dimentions set on SVG itself
<br>
<a href="#" class="btn btn--green">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
        <path d="M37 33a3 3 0 0 0 2.2-1L61 10.2V91a3 3 0 0 0 6 0V10.2L88.8 32a3 3 0 0 0 4.2-4.2L66.1.8a3 3 0 0 0-.4-.3l-.3-.1a3 3 0 0 0-.3-.2 3 3 0 0 0-.3 0l-.2-.1a3 3 0 0 0-1.2 0h-.2a3 3 0 0 0-.3.1 3 3 0 0 0-.3.2l-.3.1a3 3 0 0 0-.4.4L35 27.8a3 3 0 0 0 2.1 5.1Z"></path>
        <path d="M125 88a3 3 0 0 0-3 3v22a9 9 0 0 1-9 9H15a9 9 0 0 1-9-9V91a3 3 0 0 0-6 0v22a15 15 0 0 0 15 15h98a15 15 0 0 0 15-15V91a3 3 0 0 0-3-3Z"></path>
    </svg> Button With Icon
</a>
```

The flex box doesn't have any way of knowing button width (max-width) doesn't count because all the sizing algorithms use `width` and not `max-width` for calculations. You need to set explicit `width` either on `<svg>` or in `.btn svg`.

I suggest using `1 rem` as width on SVG because it is relative to the font size.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```css
:root {
    --green: hsl(150.22deg 60.35% 44.51%);
    --green-dark: hsl(150.22deg 60.35% 35%);
    --green-light: hsl(148.89deg 87.1% 93.92%);
    --blue: hsl(202.86deg 77.78% 15.88%);
}

.btn {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 0.5rem;
    
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-radius: 9999px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    user-select: none;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
}

.btn--green {
    background-color: var(--green);
    color: white;
}

.btn svg {
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    fill: #fff;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn btn--green">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
        <path d="M37 33a3 3 0 0 0 2.2-1L61 10.2V91a3 3 0 0 0 6 0V10.2L88.8 32a3 3 0 0 0 4.2-4.2L66.1.8a3 3 0 0 0-.4-.3l-.3-.1a3 3 0 0 0-.3-.2 3 3 0 0 0-.3 0l-.2-.1a3 3 0 0 0-1.2 0h-.2a3 3 0 0 0-.3.1 3 3 0 0 0-.3.2l-.3.1a3 3 0 0 0-.4.4L35 27.8a3 3 0 0 0 2.1 5.1Z"></path>
        <path d="M125 88a3 3 0 0 0-3 3v22a9 9 0 0 1-9 9H15a9 9 0 0 1-9-9V91a3 3 0 0 0-6 0v22a15 15 0 0 0 15 15h98a15 15 0 0 0 15-15V91a3 3 0 0 0-3-3Z"></path>
    </svg>
    Button With Icon
</a>

<br>

<a href="#" class="btn btn--green">
    Button Without Icon
</a>
```